# PHP Mail Sending via SMTP only to BCC receivers

Tags: php, email, smtp, mailing-list

I am writing a mailing List in php and need a way to force while sending a mail via smtp (Postfix) on localhost just really sending that mail to the BCC receivers.

(Having To and Cc headers sending them in the mail, but not sending the mail TO them)

The reason: If a mail is sent to the list it was sent to those receivers before; In the php script, I edit the mail (Removing forbidden Words, adding a footer with signout-link etc.) and want to send it than via smtp (mail() isnt good, it does no error handling)

Is there any Class or simple way to do that? or is it possible to stay in the postfix queue (The Mail is piped to the php-script)

The Mail, I send has as to: the mailing.list-adress (Because it has to be shown that the mail was delivered to the mailing list) and all other Tos, but the script should not send them to that adresses, it just should send to the bcc adresses.

**The Mail-Flow is**

Sender => specific-list@server.de => lists@server.de => php-programm => drop

Every 5 Minutes (Or other time the user specified) the List will be rolled out:

mail in database => script => receipients as bcc, to is list-adress (specific-list@server.de)

The Mail looks like:

```
From: original-sender@original-server.org
To: specific-list@server.de, <any other tos from original mail>
Cc: <any ccs from original mail>
Bcc: <all the list subscribers> //JUST REALLY SEND TO THIS ADRESSES
Subject: [Listname | Topicid] Topic Name

Content:
<original content>
--
signature for unsubscribe, etc.
```

I have an Idea how I could solve this, but need help for doing it.

1. I create a internal mail-address, that forwards to my real receipients
2. I send the mail to that address
3. Postfix has to handle that mail not as an outgoing mail but as a new mail delivered to that adress.
4. Because it is a received mail, postfix doesnt deliver to all other Receivers, it just delivers to that specifix address (that is a Forwarding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you send mail, by the rules established universally, you need to have a To recipient.  If you want to send the mail to yourself or to an address just for the purpose, fine.  Once you have a To you can go ahead and create your bccs.

Comment: Ok, than I just didn't formed my question right. See the last Line in the Edit. I want to have the tos and ccs in the mail header, but don't want the script to deliver to that adresses. It just should deliver to the bcc (in other case it would be trivial). The reason: I want the mail to look just at the mailing-list would be your adress. So if you send to mailing@list.de the to still will be mailing@list.de but the mail will be delivered (via bcc) to every single receipient.

Comment: I understood your original question.  You can’t do that.  You must have at least one To: address defined.  Now what you can do is iterate over the list with something like `foreach` and queue up a separate email for each person on the list using their email address as the To: header for that particular email.

Comment: Well, mailman can do that too, so there is a way to do that. The mailing list MUST be in to. The real receipient should not be shown. It not needs to be sent directly via smtp, it could be queued in in Postfix directly or Postfix could be configured not to send special mails to tos and ccs, the question is HOW

Comment: Now we are getting to the real question.  How to configure Postfix to send emails _as if_ they are all BCCed… see here: http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#auto_bcc

Comment: well, could have been, that I could make it just via php, but Thanks, I will read that article tonight. Well, it goes in the right direction. But the mail is built in php. Is there a posibility to ignore to and cc if a flag (Header, eg. X-SendOnly: Bcc) is set and send to bcc

Comment: As I said, you can iterate over all the addresses in a `foreach` loop and create one `to:` email per recipient.  Up to you.

Comment: The problem in that case is, that all other tos get the mail each iteration (All Tos have to be there if they were some). eg: I send a mail to: list, user1, user2 it will be sent by my mail server to those three rcpts. When I want all rcpts to be visible in TO in the sended list-mail, each of them gets the mail again.

Comment: @user1997286: I’m sorry. I’m REALLY confused. In the original question you said you wanted to send out a mass mailing by using BCC so the recipients where all hidden. Now you are asking how to include them all in the TO: field?

Comment: Well. I am at the point, where the list-adress got the mail and it is parsed. now it needs to be sent to the real rcpts. The mail should have all teh tos and ccs in the fields, that it looks like normal, but should not to be resent to them. - I think with ignoring the To and Cc in the mail in postfix (But letting it in the header) would do the job. The Bccs are already there. To them, the mail sould be sent